# What is better: var with mutable.ListMap or var with immutable.ListMap?

Tags: scala, immutability, var

I have a simple usage of `var` variable with `immutable.ListMap` type. Unfortunately a code complexity of a project does not give me a chance to move it to `immutable val`

On review I am getting a comment to change it to `var` variable with `mutable.ListMap`.
Like "you already have `var` and mutable won't make thing worse."

What do you think about that? Are there any performance metrics or code style that prohibits using of mutable vars? What is really better to choose between `mutable var` and `immutable var`?

I have read all answers for

[val-mutable versus var-immutable in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386559/val-mutable-versus-var-immutable-in-scala) and noticed one comment that got lot of likes:

> > > Prefer immutable val over immutable var over mutable val over mutable var

Are there any proofs or explanation for that statement?

Comment: Why would you change it a `mutable var`? I mean, do you need to change the reference of the object _(var)_ or mutate the object itself _(mutable)_? If you really need both, I would suggest to carefully review the design of the code. Why? Because the more you expose mutations, more easy is to break things, and harder to reason about the code. If you really need mutability for any reason, then aim to keep it closed to the minimum possible scope.

Comment: No, I do not need both, I am just thinking of a good answer on review that double mutability is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

`var` with mutable collection is a double mutability.

```
var mm : scala.collection.mutable.xxx = ???
```

This means that the collection `mm` holds can and might change over time *and/or* `mm` itself can be changed to reference a completely different collection.

Mutable collections are, occasionally, useful. Mutable variables are seldom needed and should be avoided. Mutable variables typed to mutable collections? I just don't see how that can be justified.

Answer (score 1):

`ListMap` is a good example actually, because, in multithreaded environment, you have to `synchronize` even when you only *look* at it. 
`var` assignments on the other hand are atomic, you don't need to `synchronize` at all, just mark it as `@volatile`.

This is a performance benefit, as well as reliability (whenever your stuff needs `synchronized` access, it is only a matter of time before someone forgets to code it properly).

So, yes, if you can't use "immutable val" for some reason, then definitely prefer "immutable var" over "mutable val", unless there is an explicit and concrete reason why you require your container to be mutable (e.g., the map is really huge and often updated, causing measurable performance problems).

As for "mutable var", yeah, like the other answer mentioned, I also have no idea why in the world you want to have *that*.

Comment: Using `volatile` makes assignment atomic (at significant performance cost) but you may still need to synchronise access to your data structures, even immutable ones.

Comment: Performance cost is real, but not as significant as that of synchronization. 
No, you don't need to synchronize access to immutable structures.

Comment: Immutability does not guarantee thread safety because immutable objects can have mutable state that is not thread safe. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934690/are-scala-immutable-collections-thread-safe).

Comment: The answer to the question you referenced, says that it is thread safe :D. And it actually _is_. "Exchange values between threads through a volatile var" - is _exactly_ what we are talking about here.

Comment: Immutable objects cannot have mutable state, that's an oxymoron. They can use mutable state _during construction_ (as that doc states), but that's inconsequential. Once the (immutable) object is created, it is safe.

Comment: Immutability is a property of the interface, not the implementation. For example an object may store memoized values of previous invocations which requires mutable state but retains the immutability of the interface. Any object which contains a `lazy` value fits into this category. You should never assume that an immutable object is thread safe.

Comment: It is _possible_ to make an immutable object unsafe. But, if you do that, it is just a bug in your implementation. We are talking about scala standard library here, and I challenge you to find one immutable object there, that is not thread safe, because of mutable state, it somehow uses internally, outside of construction time.  And no, `lazy` values are safe.

Comment: Sigh. "You should not assume that an object with an immutable interface is thread safe" OK?

Comment: Nope. You actually _should_ assume that (at least as much as you should assume, that a function called `reasUser` does not write the contents of you /etc/passwd into a socket). And if you ever run into an instance where it does not hold, you should file a bug.

Comment: As for your challenge, the documentation for `immutable.List` says "the implementation [...] can lead to race conditions in some multi-threaded scenarios" and "an unsynchronized non-volatile read from another thread may observe the object in an invalid state. Note that such a read is not guaranteed to *ever* see the written object at all". [Emphasis added]

Comment: @Tim the "challenge" specifically mentioned _outside of construction_.